# Session Lost when changing the location with window.location in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-variables

I'm displaying a message.
Like so:

```
//ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "redirect", errortext + " window.location='" +
//Page.ResolveUrl("~") + newpage + "';", true);

//Response.Write("<script>" + errortext + "</script>");
//Response.Write("<script>top.location.href='" + Page.ResolveUrl("~") + newpage + "'</script>");

var page = HttpContext.Current.CurrentHandler as Page;
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, page.GetType(), "alert", "alert('" + errortext + "');window.location ='" + Page.ResolveUrl("~") + newpage + "';", true);
```

Note: As you can see, I've tried 3 different formats.  After the script redirect, the session is lost.  The page-url is nearly the same:
Meaning it's https://whatever//hello.aspx to https://whatever/hello2.aspx

I cannot use 'Response.Redirect' because that would kill the message.  The redirection does happen, the page comes up.  However I discover quite quickly that the page doesn't have the information it needs to operate.

Comment: What makes you think the session is lost?

Comment: All my Session Variables had a value before.  After they do not.  
Session("customername") = "whatever";
On the new page: It has no value.

Comment: Without waiting for anybody to answer the real question.  I can think of an option.  That involves 'Response.Redirect'.  I set a 'Session' variable with the alert and after redirect on the new page it sees it, displays it and deletes it.  
I'd rather do this in some-sortof parameter (or form object).

Comment: Tried removing Page.ResolveUrl... Same results.

Comment: The 'response.redirect' and the alert on the new page is what I'm using.  It's ugly, but it works.